# Redirect to different domain while preserve subdomains and query parameters and also enforce https using web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis

Using the Web.config only, I need to redirect all traffic to a new domain, yet also:
1) preserve subdomains
2) preserve query parameters
3) if "http" and not "https" change to "https" while doing the above

I can easily handle enforcing HTTPS, and I have seen many references to redirects for domains, but have not found any that preserve the subdomains while changing to the root domain.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^localhost(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^127\.0\.0\.1(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
    </rule>       
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

'The above works to change http to https, but does not help with the need to change the domain. I have also seen this below which almost works:'

```
<rule name="redirect" enabled="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="false" pattern="^(.*)\.foo\.com" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}.bar.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

`...but removes the subdomain:`

`http://x.foo.com` > `https://.bar.com`

Examples of what it needs to do:

`http://x.foo.com` > `https://x.bar.com`

`https://y.foo.com` > `https://y.bar.com`

`https://x.foo.com/blah.aspx?param=blue > https://x.bar.com/blah.aspx?param=blue`

`http://y.foo.com/blah.aspx?param=blue > https://y.bar.com/blah.aspx?param=blue`

Comment: According to your descritpion and url rewrite rule, I have created a test demo on my side, it works well.  We could redirect from http://x.foo.com > https://x.bar.com.Is there any other rewrite rul in your web.config?

Comment: Thanks Brando. I posted a solution that I does both HTTP > HTTPS and redirect to the new domain (while preserving any query parameters). See below. There might be a way to combine into one rule.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have come up with the following solution that does exactly what I have needed (see above requirements). I did this by adding two independent rule blocks: one to ensure HTTPS, and the other to do a redirect to the other domain if necessary. I sense that this does double the traffic if the visit needs both 1) HTTP to HTTPS and 2) direct to the new domain (from *.foo.com > *.bar.com) but at least it works. Not sure if it could be tweaked into one rule to save hits?

```
   <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" />
          <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^localhost(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^127\.0\.0\.1(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirect to new domain" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)$" />
          <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="false" pattern="^(.*)\.foo\.com" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}.bar.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```